# Openssl handshake failed when using getInputStream() on Facebook profile picture in android sdk

Tags: android, facebook, inputstream, facebook-sdk-4.0, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to create user profile page for my app. 
I succeed with connecting to Facebook, so i have the user basic profile using            `userProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();`
Now i am trying to create a drawable of the user profile picture to put in a image view. For this I created a inputstream to fetch the image(running on asyncTask)

```
            Bitmap x;
            url =  new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/939344862743414/picture?height=200&width=200");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-agent","Mozilla/4.0");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            x = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
```

However no matter what I do,the app failed and crash when it reach the    connection.getInputStream(). The error is    javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted
I couldn't find any help on the web .It doesn't seem as an authorization problem because I can connect to Facebook and fetch data.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is created by the url. As the **URL** contains `https` which means the web server certificate is issued by a well known CA, so that you can make a secure request. As you are using `HttpURLConnection` it doesn't support secured URL.

So you can enable the access to secured url (`https://..`) by using `URLConnection` in the place of HttpURLConnection. So modify the following line:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

with this one:

```
URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

[Detail information can be found here.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)